# Creating Unique Identifers In Calculated Columns in Spotire

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

I have a table of data looking at vertical distribution of salinity types by depths at different locations in the ocean. I can calculate a salinity type / flag, and what I would like to do in Spotfire is to then create a unique ID for each "package" of continuous salinity types at each location, so that I can then look at a distribution of thickness of "packages" at each location.

How can I create using Spotfire calculated columns a unique id for continuous packages (ie., if two or more depths have the same type at without being separated by another type, they are continuous) at each location, labeling them using their location and then a number for the package number (starting the count from greatest depth at that location). I only want to label the packages that are "Red" Type

I have created the appropriate workflow in Excel but am having trouble converting the formulas to Spotfire calculated columns

The formulas (Excel) are below and these are what I need to convert Spotfire calculated columns

Step 1 = =IF(C2=1,0.5,0)

Step 2 = =IF(C2=1,E1+D2,0)

Step 3 = =IF(C3=0,E2, 0)

See table / image below.

[image]

Comment: what is the datasource for this? a RDMS?

Comment: @scsimon it's just coming back a excel file

Comment: @scsimon, did that answer your questions? Any luck? I'm at my wits end on this one

Comment: It did but I couldn't figure out a way in Spotfire unfortunately. You stumped me!

Comment: haha not a problem - I'm trying to either find a combination of excel / Spotfire or I'm guessing a script might be the best answer rather than everything in a calculated column

Comment: @scsimon, How would I write to following formaluas as calculated columns in Spotfire. The workflow works in excel, now I just need to translate the language hopefully!

=IF(C2=1,0.5,0) 

=IF(C2=1,E1+D2,0)

=IF(C3=0,E2, 0)

Comment: The key is being able to do those calculates over every "Location"

Comment: For step 2, this seems like it would be the formula for column E, yet you reference column E. can you explain?

Comment: @scsimon - my mistake, Column C = Type, D = Step1, E = Step2. Does that help enough?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I understood that association, but if `E = Step2` and `Step 2 =IF(C2=1,E1+D2,0)` then that is a circular reference. In the formula which would be calculating the value for E you use the value of E which wouldn't exist yet. Are you stating that, say for E2 this would be the formula and it would iterate + 1 as you move down the rows... thus E accesses the previous row E value?

Comment: a yes, I see the issue - I think I copied something incorrectly, I will get on that, sorry about that!